# Proving that if $a$ is not a quadratic residue, then $a^{p'}\equiv -1\pmod p$: Is my proof correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, quadratic-residues

On Courant/Robbins' "What is mathematics?", it says that:

Due to Fermat's Little Theorem, we have $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$. This suggests that we define $p'=\frac{p-1}{2}$ and factor the previous congruence as:

$$(a^{p'}-1)(a^{p'}+1)\equiv 0 \pmod p \tag{$\color{red}{☭}$}$$

And then we must have $a^{p'}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ or $a^{p'}\equiv -1 \pmod p$. Now, If $a$ is a quadratic residue, that is, for some $x$, we have:

$$a\equiv x^2\pmod p$$

From this, we have:

$$a^{p'}\equiv x^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod p$$

That is: If $a$ is a quadratic residue, then $a^{p'}\equiv 1\pmod p$ and he says that it can easily be proven that if $a$ is not a quadratic residue, then $a^{p'}\equiv -1\pmod p$. I suppose I know how to prove it:

> - If $a$ is a quadratic residue, then $a^{p'}\equiv 1\pmod p$. With contrapositive, we obtain that $a^{p'}\not\equiv 1\pmod p$ then $a$ is not a quadratic residue.
> - Also, if $a^{p'}\not\equiv 1\pmod p$ due to the Fermat's little theorem, we have $(\color{red}{☭})$ and as $a^{p'}-1\not\equiv 0 \pmod p$ we must have $a^{p'}+1\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Did you prove that if $a$ is not a quadratic residue then we can't have $a^{p'}\equiv1\pmod p$?

Comment: Hint:  how many solutions are there to $a^{p'}\equiv1\pmod p$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No, I used the contrapositive to show that if $a^{p'}\not\equiv 1\pmod p$ then $a$ is not a quadratic residue.

Comment: Aren't you trying to prove that, if $a$ is not a quadratic residue, then $a^{p'}\equiv-1\pmod p$?  The contrapositive of that would be if $a^{p'}\not\equiv-1\pmod p$, then $a$ is a quadratic residue

Comment: @J.W.Tanner If $a$ is not a quadratic residue, we obtain that $a^{p'}-1 \not\equiv 0\pmod p$. From Fermat's little theorem, we get $(a^{p'}-1)(a^{p'}+1)\equiv 0 \pmod p $ and then we must have that $a^{p'}+1\equiv 0 \pmod p$, no?

Comment: A proof was given that if $a$ is a quadratic residue, then $a^{p'}\equiv1\pmod p$.  How do you know that $a^{p'}\equiv1\pmod p$ can't be true for non-quadratic residues as well?   (See my hint above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is not complete.

It has been shown that, if $a$ is a quadratic residue, then $a^{p'}\equiv1\pmod p$.

Furthermore, it has been shown that, if $a$ is not a quadratic residue, then $a^{p'}\equiv\pm1\pmod p$.

To show that, if $a$ is not a quadratic residue, then $a^{p'}\equiv-1\pmod p$,

it remains to be shown that, if $a$ is not a quadratic residue, then $a^{p'
}\not\equiv1\pmod p$.

To show that, consider how many quadratic residues there are,

and how many solutions $a^{p'}-1\equiv0\pmod p$ could have.

Comment: We know that $a$ being a quadratic residue implies $a^{p'}\equiv 1 \pmod p$. Other quadratic non-residues can't be a solution to $a^{p'}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ because there are $p'$ quadratic residues and all $p'$ quadratic residues are solutions and  $a^{p'}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ can have at most $p'$ solutions. So, for a quadratic non-residue, we have $a^{p'} \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: Now due to Fermat's little theorem, we have $(a^{p'}-1)(a^{p'}+1)\equiv 0 \pmod p$ and as we seen that $a^{p'}\not\equiv 1 \pmod p$ then $a^{p'}\not\equiv -1 \pmod p$. Is it correct now?

Comment: @BillyRubina:  I believe so